# elasticsearch can't understand signed date

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I'm trying to save a document with the current values on Elasticsearch (1.7) from my ruby script.

```
{
"P577 ": [{
    "snaktype": "value",
    "property": "P577",
    "hash": "2a7ea4b81277334f08c4cd9efbce76001505a481",
    "datavalue": {
        "value": {
            "time": "+2015-10-16T00:00:00Z",
            "timezone": 0,
            "before": 0,
            "after": 0,
            "precision": 11,
            "calendarmodel": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727"
        },
        "type": "time"
    },
    "datatype": "time"
}]
}
```

turns out that ES don't know how to handle with the `time` (`+2015-10-16T00:00:00Z`).
Is there a way to make ES understand this kind of date?
I know I can maybe using mapping, but what I showed is a very small piece of a giant JSON, with lots of nested nodes ([like here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q83.json))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is with a custom mapping and changing how ES [detects dates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#_customising_detected_date_formats):

What I've done in the past is to

1. Insert a document.
2. Extract the mapping (see how [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)).
3. Update the mapping to my liking.
4. Do a PUT of the new mapping... And to do this, you might need to create a different type, as sometimes ES cannot replace a mapping on the fly.

I've never done this with dates, but had to do it a few times with the way a field is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

"+2015-10-16T00:00:00Z" remove plus sign and try it,.
 "2015-10-16T00:00:00Z"